# Changed WooCommerce setting and crashed entire site. Just see blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I was working on a clients WooCommerce powered WordPress site and changed the image size of the main product image in the standard settings tab and all of a sudden the entire site is down and all I see is a blank page or sometimes this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/flfl7067/public_html/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/functions.php on line 201

When I go to `line 201`, there's nothing wrong with the code so I'm completely lost. I can't even load the admin panel any more to change the setting back.

Here is the code from around `line 193` onwards:

```
/**
 * Include custom post typest.
 *
 */
require_once( PRESSCORE_DIR . '/post-types.php' );

if ( !class_exists('Mobile_Detect') ) {

    /**
     * Mobile detection library.

     */
    require_once( PRESSCORE_EXTENSIONS_DIR . '/mobile-detect.php' );

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what is on line 190-210 of the functions.php file

Comment: Do you have any HEREDOC's in your functions.php?

Comment: What is in `/mobile-detect.php`? It's hard to say but that's probably where the error is... "around 193" doesn't help that much.

Comment: @doublesharp there are no HEREDOCS in the function PHP.

Comment: If you remove that function, is the site still broken?

Comment: Or just comment out the `require_once` to see if it will load.

Comment: I commented out both // required lines and still get same error. The site is flexalite.com.au if that helps

Comment: The error is the same with both commented out? What is on exactly line 201? If it is an include, can you post the contents of that file? Also what are the values of the constants.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is generally the correct one. Turns out there was just some random code distributed throughout the document [no idea how or who placed it there] but its fixed now. Thanks @howlin and @doublesharp for fast answers.